# js6 class in module namespace, private class?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I've got a module that I would like to extend. And I would like to create a class inside. Something like:

```
let my_module = {
  init = () => {
    console.log("this inits my module")
  }
};
```

```
$.extend(my_module, {
    extension: {
        variable: false,

        myObject : new MyObject(),

        //next line does not work, expects key
        class MyObject {
          constructor() {
            console.log("my object constructed");
          }
        }
}
```

Now I'm wondering how I should declare the `MyObject` class so that its declaration is not global but used in module? I'd like to call it from the outside like this: `let new_inst = new my_module.extension.MyObject();`. Is that even possible? How to declare that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class), where you add your class as a value to the property `MyObject`. However, if you do this using `new MyObject()` within your `extension` won't work as the `MyObject` class is now part of your object. Instead, you could use a getter to create a new instance for you (this is slightly different to what you have at the moment as this will create a new instance each time you access `myObject`, rather than giving you the same instance).

```
$.extend(my_module, {
  extension: {
    variable: false,

    get myObject() {
      return new this.MyObject();
    },

    MyObject: class {
      constructor() {
        console.log("my object constructed");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```js
const o = {
  extension: {
    variable: false,

    get myObject() {
      return new this.MyObject()
    },

    MyObject: class {
      constructor() {
        console.log("my object constructed");
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(new o.extension.MyObject());
console.log(o.extension.myObject);
```

Also, as a side note, your first object has a syntax error, `init` should be an object property, not a variable so change `init = () => ...` to be. `init: () => {}`:

```
let my_module = {
  init: () => {
    console.log("this inits my module")
  }
};
```